# Reading Jennifer5 Monitor

Tags: performance, monitoring, jennifer

I am using `Jennifer5` to monitor my webservices, but I am confused about the information on the monitor. I have attached an image, and if you see the circled part of the graphs, they are showing future time for current day, and does have some data, is this data an average of the past data, or some algorithm used on past data to predict the possible future data? I cannot say what those values exactly are.

[image: an example jennifer5 snippet]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the data of the previous day, as described for one of the charts in the manual of `Jennifer5`;

[image]